# Backup recovery drives Windows 7 64-bit (Toshiba and Acer)

Tags: backup

I have Toshiba Satellite and Acer Aspire laptops. I back up data on regular basis and also have recovery discs for these machines. I don't rely on optical recovery media much because in my experience, they give error when you want them to work.

I would like to copy the recovery partitions AS IT IS on external HDDs so that in case of drive failure, I can restore the machine to factory condition from the external HDD (in case optical media fails) using Ubuntu Live or something similar. These partitions are not visible through windows explorer.

I am not good at command-line interface so GUI based programs are welcome. Searching through the forum led me to Drive Snapshot, seems to be a good piece of software. The goal is
- Back up partition as it is on external HDD
- When in need it should be available without much hassle to copy on a new HDD.

Comment: Also see [Looking for a software capable of cloning a System drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/61317)

Answer (score 1):

I would say

`Acronis True Image` / plenty of choices good software http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/

`Norton Ghost` / very good piece of software, price is higher http://us.norton.com/ghost/

If you want something free, there is a

`Clonezilla` / special distribution of linux with simple gui-like interface http://clonezilla.org/